# Can STIM be used to numerically find all the stabilisers of a model?

Tags: stim

Can the package stim be used to exhaustively find all the stabilisers of a model? If so, how? I have a gauge code I am studying and we're unsure if we've found all the stabilisers or only a subset.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a circuit implementing the model, you can use [`stim.TableauSimulator.peek_z`](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/main/doc/python_api_reference_vDev.md#stim.TableauSimulator.peek_z) (and variants) to check whether a measurement is deterministic.

Iterate over the operations of the circuit, feeding them to the tableau simulator. Whenever you are about to perform a measurement first check if it is deterministic. Unless you're doing something particularly fancy, the number of deterministic measurements should be the number of stabilizers.

```
# note: v1.10 or later

import stim

def count_deterministic_measurements(measurement_loop: stim.Circuit) -> int:
    result = 0
    simulator = stim.TableauSimulator()

    # Do a few iterations to get into the steady state.
    simulator.do(measurement_loop * 10)

    # Do an iteration counting the number of determined measurements.
    for instruction in measurement_loop:
        # TODO: recurse into sub-loops if needed
        assert isinstance(instruction, stim.CircuitInstruction)
        # TODO: generalize this to work for all measurement operations.
        assert instruction.name not in ["MX", "MY", "MRX", "MRY", "MPP"]

        if instruction.name in ["M", "MR"]:
            for gate_target in instruction.targets_copy():
                assert gate_target.is_qubit_target
                is_random = simulator.peek_z(gate_target.value) == 0
                if not is_random:
                    result += 1
        simulator.do(instruction)

    return result
```

Testing it on stim's built in surface code:

```
test_circuit = stim.Circuit.generated("surface_code:rotated_memory_x", distance=5, rounds=100)
test_measurement_loop = [instruction for instruction in test_circuit if isinstance(instruction, stim.CircuitRepeatBlock)][0].body_copy()
assert count_deterministic_measurements(test_measurement_loop) == 5*5 - 1
```

Comment: In the case of measurement-based codes such as the topological cluster states there are no deterministic measurements (only multiplications of several measurements are deterministic). 
Can you still use STIM to find the stabilizers of check operators assuming you have the circuit?

Comment: @YaronJarach yes that will work fine